# Keeping data around in an entangled state: use cases

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, entanglement

I'm following the IBM Quantum roadmap and really excited to see what the next 3 years bring. As part of the unveiling, they mentioned that the 1000 Qubit machine goal will really stabilize things with error correction and general stability in place. The advances from that point onwards switches to a software problem rather than a hardware one (notwithstanding lots of work will continue!).

I'm playing around with Qiskit and my limited understanding. In entanglement, due to the current fragility we don't want to hold that data any longer than is necessary for fear of losing it. In Classical we like to hold onto data in memory until we need it. Assuming the hardware gives us the stability to maintain a longer lived Quantum state, what benefits or scenarios could that unlock? I'm trying to think of use cases to explore in Qiskit and simulate a long lived state but my fundamental lack of knowledge here is holding me back. I'd love an insight into what you folks think we could do if we had that stability.

Comment: I'd say it just makes any task easier if the states remain coherent longer. Certainly it would help for things like communication tasks